# ¿Como implemento correcciones automáticas (de forma nativa o pluggins)?

Tags: plugin, vim

Tengo como editor de código Vim 8.1, y quiero que de alguna forma, se pueda hacer algo como en VSCode o Sublime, que cada vez que escriba una palabra mal en el código me la marque o directamente la corrija.

Por poner un ejemplo tonto:
Si escribo mal la palabra (`class`), en muchas ocasiones me he ido con una palabra mal escrita y tengo que buscar un buen rato en el código para encontarme con una simple letra que cambie por otra (`clzss`).

No se si exista algun plugin para esto o si se puede configurar de alguna manera directa en VIM.

Mi .vimrc
https://github.com/SetCain/dotfiles/blob/master/.vimrc

Comment: tendrías que ver en https://vimawesome.com/ alguno que soporte syntaxis de los lenguajes que utilizas

Answer (score 1):

Bien, si lo que buscas es una autocorreción automática de palabras mal escritas, la forma nativa de hacerlo en **Vim** es usar el comando [`iabbrev`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#:iabbrev). Por ejemplo, en el caso que mencionas, deberías ejecutar:

```
:iab clzss class
```

Con esta configuración que podrías dejar en tu `.vimrc` harías que cada vez que escribas `clzss` automáticamente se corrija a `class`. Esto es sumamente útil en la mayoría de los casos pero puede ser bastante trabajoso en otros dónde puedas llegar a tener "códigos" o "palabras" que se puedan escribir tanto en mayúsculas como en minúsculas o incluso combinando ambos. Para esto hay algunos pluggins:

- [vim-abolish](https://github.com/tpope/vim-abolish), básicamente da más flexibilidad a la hora de definir las abreviaciones
- [vim-autocorrect](https://github.com/panozzaj/vim-autocorrect), ya trae incorporada una lista importante de "errores" de tipeo, obviamente orientado al idioma inglés.

Answer (score 1):

Lo mejor para tu caso no es una simple corrección por diccionario sino verdadera corrección semántica.

Hay un par de plugins que sirven para hacer eso. El único que yo he probado es [ale](https://github.com/w0rp/ale) ya que me ha funcionado muy bien desde el principio y no he querido probar otros.

El mencionado plugin usa herramientas de revisión externas (en el caso de java, puede usar javac) para proporcionar revisión a tu código poco después de que lo escribes. Funciona bastante bien sin necesidad de configuración puede usar muchas herramientas además del compilador de java, además de ser extremadamente configurable si te interesa.